# When I added Text Input layout to my xml file its working but when i click on date picker class app is crashing

Tags: android

I am making my edittext to material design (using TextInputLayout).It is working fine .But when I click on my DatePicker the app is crashing saying:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.NumberPicker.getChildCount()' on a null object reference
```

My gradle file as below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

I don't understand, removing the TextInputLayout fixes the problem...

**NOTE:** I have defined `Theme.AppCompat.Light` in manifest

Comment: Sorry forgot to add  , compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3,,minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25'  and 25 App compat Library

Answer (score 0):

Your `NumberPicker` is null, It is either not initialized or  If you have used `findViewById`, It has not been found, therefore, calling `getChildCount` on a null object will throw NullPointerException.

Try to resolve the `NumberPicker` reference and make sure that it is not null and found in your View/Activity/Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.widget.NumberPicker.getChildCount()' on a null object
>   reference

From this, you can see that the exception is a NullPointerException. and it says that, getChildCount() method was called on a null point. Which means that, the object of type `NumberPicker` is null.

So, if you've initialized the object, please check the initialization part of your code. And your findViewById might be also not working as well if the ID wasn't found in the XML file.